# Find the index of clicked element with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

My html code is

```
<input type="button" class="buttonclose marleft fleft clrPric" value="X">
<input type="button" class="buttonclose marleft fleft clrPric" value="X"> 
<input type="button" class="buttonclose marleft fleft clrPric" value="X">
<input type="button" class="buttonclose marleft fleft clrPric" value="X">
```

I gave jquery like

```
 $('.clrPric').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).index());
 });
```

It shows only 7 in console. No other elements with this class.
I want to get the number of the clicked button.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: working ok at my end . please check it again. i have tested here http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/sUGEG/

Comment: I do not understand what your exact problem is. What do you expect to happen? Are there other buttons mixed in with the html mark-up you are not showing?

Comment: Working also from my end. Please recheck by clicking rahular's jsfiddle link.

Comment: I copied your code and pasted in jsfiddle, and it works fine

Comment: Doesn't work in fist time but start to work after reload. maybe console log problem, try with `alert($(this).index())`

Comment: It worked in jsFiddle,but not in my project .But I found below anwser working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
$('.clrPric').click(function () {
    console.log($(this).index('.clrPric'));
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/EkyEZ/)